# Convert "Sat, 27 Apr 2013 08:54:17 EDT" to NSDate

Tags: nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Can somebody help in converting the text "Sat, 27 Apr 2013 08:54:17 EDT" into String. I have tried the NSDateFormatter with formatting style of "EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ" but it returns only nil value. I am able to convert valeswhich have EST, GMT but facing problem in EDT.

Comment: Just as an idea: Seems that NSDateFormatter doesn't know about the "EDT" timezone. You may either pass that in first or replace that with UTC-4. http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
```

This will return all the known timezones. You can check if EDT is there. I think it is there. Also, in the date format, you gave MMMM. It means named month (like january, february). So in your string, try giving April instead of Apr. Also, you can try giving z instead of Z.